# Wrapper isn't wrapping

Tags: html, css, containers, wrapper, word-wrap

I've set the height of my wrapper to auto so it would automatically adjust to any screen but the wrapper isn't wrapping around the inner divs. The wrapper is seems to be 150px even though I don't know why. Note: The wrapper is the container.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Playstation 4 Home Page English</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("styles/Default Style.css");
@import url("styles/Homepage.css");
@import url("styles/styles.css");
</style>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icons/Playstation-logoicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../engine1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background:#CCCCCC;">
<div id="Container">
      <div id="Header"> <img src="images/Header.png" width="400" height="95" 
  style=
  "position: absolute; 
  left: 189px;
  top:10px;">
        <div id="Social-Networks"><a href="http://www.playstation.com" title="Officiële Playstation-Website" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/Playstation-logo.png" width="36" height="36"></a><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PlayStation" title="Officiële Playstation Youtube Kanaal" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/1387937374_Youtube.png" width="36" height="36" style="margin-left:5px;"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/PlayStation" title="Officiële Playstation Twitter" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/1387937314_Twitter.png" width="36" height="36"
          style="margin-left:5px;"></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/PlayStation" title="Officiële Playstation Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/1387947454_Facebook.png" width="36" height="36" style="margin-left:5px;"></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="ContentHolder">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
          <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='homepage.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Artikelen</span></a>
              <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Nederlands</span></a> </li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Engels</span></a> </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='gallery.html'><span>Galerij</span></a></li>
            <li style="float:right" class='last'><a href='#'><span>Over</span></a></li>
            <li style="float:right" class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images"><ul>
<li><img src="../data1/images/SonyPlaystationGeschiedenisSlider.jpg" alt="SonyPlaystationGeschiedenisSlider" title="Het onstaan van Het Gaming Icoon" id="wows1_0"/></li>
<li><img src="../data1/images/RemotePlayPS4PSVita.jpg" alt="RemotePlayPS4PSVita" title="Remote-Play voor de PS4 en PS Vita" id="wows1_1"/></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
<a href="#" title="De geschiedenis van de Sony Playstation">1</a>
<a href="#" title="Remote-Play voor de PS4 en PS Vita">2</a>
</div></div>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../engine1/script.js"></script>
          <div id="Side-Content"> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://output78.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&amp;id=815822&amp;hash=b0095ae8bebb910e5dc0f397a646173e"></script>
          </div>
          <div id="ContentHolder1">
            <h1>Welkom op onze Playstation 4 News Website!</h1>
            adjskl;fjaklsfdjaflds;
            <hr>
            lkdajf;lkdaj;fas
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Copyright">&copy;Copyright Mounteder Abdulrazag, Tom Borghouts</div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body { 
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px
}

#Container {
    height:auto;
  width: 975px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:#006;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#Wrapper {
    margin:auto;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  width: 975px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#ContentHolder {
  width:975px;
  background-color:#0F0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  overflow:hidden;

}

#Header {
  height: 125px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 975px;
}

#Social-Networks {
  height:36px;
  width:164px;
  margin-right:230px;
  margin-top:80px;
  float:right;
}

#Social-Networks img {
  opacity:1;  
}

#Social-Networks img:hover {
  opacity:0.9;
}

#ContentHolder1 {
  width:650px;
  height:925px;
  margin-left:42px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:-10px;
  background-color:transparent;
  color: #8B8B8B;
}

#Side-Content {
  width:250px;
  height:600px;
  float:right;
  background-color:transparent;
}

#Content1 {
  width: 725px;
  height:1235px;
  color: #9B9B9B;
  margin-top:-18px;
  margin-left:5px;
  background-color: #03C;
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

hr {
    height: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#Copyright {
  height: 25px;
  width: 975px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #0000d3;
  text-align:left;
  font-family:"Open Sans";
}
```

Comment: What color is the wrapper??

Comment: Whitesmoke. But I fixed it ;).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#Container {
    float: left;              //this
    display: inline-block;    // or this
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. It only dragged the wrapper to the left and it's still 150px :/.

Comment: I fixed it. It seems that the CSS Menu (the navigation bar) was the container of most of the part. I just closed the div where it's supposed to end and it was solved. Thanks for the help :).